# Ho to use bold and header tag in <div>tag?

Tags: html, xslt

I am using XSL and under  `<div>` tag i am passing the text content of `<div>` filled by user  from one screen to another and at last i am storing the user's data in local db.It is basically 3 screen where on the first screen it shows value of the data stored in db and on 2nd screen user can edit that data and on 3rd screen the user's edited data is shown and stored into db. The only problem is I am trying to make certain text `bold` or `italic` on 2nd screen but i am unable to do so. I am attaching the code for 2nd and 3rd screen.
At this point I am lost. Any suggestion will be appreciated.Thanks.

`XSL for 2nd Screen`

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" class="graphtable">
    <tr>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//faml/response/stresponsedto/security_tips">
                <xsl:for-each select="//faml/response/stresponsedto/security_tips/stdto">
                    <td>
                        <div class="carousel" contenteditable="true" id="post-text">
                            <xsl:value-of select="securitytips"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </tr>
    <script>
    </table>
```

`XSL for 3rd screen`

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" class="graphtable">
    <tr>
        <td class="headingalign" width="10%" >Security Tips</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-right: 10px">
            <div class="carousel">
                <xsl:value-of select="//faml/request/fldsandt"/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: May be you can try using span tag?

Comment: Can you include a sample xml in your question?

Answer (score 0):

1. You could do this on the 2nd screen:

```
  <div class="carousel" contenteditable="true" id="post-text">
    <b><xsl:value-of select="securitytips"/></b>
  </div>
```

2. or add a class to the div (recommended by the CSS police)

```
  <div class="carousel bold" contenteditable="true" id="post-text">
    <xsl:value-of select="securitytips"/>
  </div>
```

and to the CSS

```
.bold{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: but using this will make the complete content in bold.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by 'certain text'. 2. If you want the user to edit the text, you can only bold/italic parts of it if you are using a wysiwyg editor, which is much more complex than what you have presented here.